# Can I Insert multiple rows based on a query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert a load of things into my database

Written out longhand the queries would be something like this (but with more things!)

```
Insert into MyTable (country_id, event) values (1001, 'up')
Insert into MyTable (country_id, event) values (1001, 'down')
Insert into MyTable (country_id, event) values (1002, 'up')
Insert into MyTable (country_id, event) values (1003, 'down')
....
Insert into MyTable (country_id, event) values (9999, 'up')
Insert into MyTable (country_id, event) values (9999, 'down')
```

Can I write some kind of magic sql join/merge wonder query that will get all the `country_ids` and all 'event' types and create the hundreds of insert statements I require?

Edit:
There is a table for country. Which should be inserted into MyTable are a result of an sql query, and each result of that query needs the 'up' and 'down' row in MyTable. There are enough that I don't want to curate the query by hand.

In real there are more than 'up' and 'down' but they could be entered by hand, or as a result of a further query.

Comment: data you want to insert are in a table or in a text file?

Comment: Do you actually want to generate this data? Do you have tables for `country` and `event` data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create cartesian product of countries and event list and insert them at once:

```
insert into MyTable (country_id, event)
select countries.country_id, 
       e.[event]
  from countries
 cross join
 (
   select 'Up' [event]
   union all
   select 'Down'
 ) e
```

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the

```
 Insert into MyTable (country_id, event) values
```

and replace it with

```
 Insert into MyTable (country_id, event) values (1001, 'down'),
 (1002, 'up'),
 (1003, 'down')
```

Or you could look at `BULK INSERT` or `bcp` if your data is coming from a file.

Or if you know what the countries and events are,

```
Insert MyTable (country_id, event) 
SELECT countryid, event 
FROM country, events
```

will put all combinations into your table

Answer (score 2):

You could join `VALUES` like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (country_id, event) 
VALUES (1001, 'up'),(1001, 'down'),(1002, 'up'),(1003, 'down')
```

Comment: I would still have to hand create the huge list of brackets and would get confused and angry after 500 or so!

Answer (score 2):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0355b/10

**[DEMO SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0355b/10)**

**Note:** Both table schema must be same

Comment: Did not solve my issue but +1 for sql fiddle! nice little tester tool